# Unexplained Syntax Error in Html

Tags: python, html, django, syntax

Hey I've been having a problem with my HTML code where I keep getting syntax errors and can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
    <input type="date" name="DueDate" value="{{task.due_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}">
```

The editor I am using is pyCharm and it keeps giving me an error under ":" and "" }". 
The purpose of this input is to display the date represented by task.due_date in the correct format. task.due_date is datefield created within the model using django. When trying to fix the error pyCharm states that I need to put in }} where the error is.

Any help?

Comment: As the formatter for SO shows, you can't put double quotes inside double quotes. use single quotes on the inside: `"{{task.due_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}"`

Comment: I just tried that and it still has the same error.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're receiving, and what type of django file you're working on? It looks like a template?

Comment: Okay when I tested it, it works so thank you! But in the editor it still shows an error.

Comment: IDEs like to warn you about things that, according to their checks, might possibly be a problem.

Comment: Django & even more so tastypie both are not well supported by PyCharm's built-in analysis.